# How to display All "name" values in array using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

```
    var data=[{

    "name": "cA",
    "leaf": false,
    "largeIconId": null,
    "label": "cA",
    "hideAllSearchFilters": false,
    "guidePage": null,
    "expanded": false,
    "defaultSearchCategory": false,
    "childCategories": [{
        "name": "cA-A",
        "leaf": false,
        "largeIconId": null,
        "label": "cA-A",
        "hideAllSearchFilters": false,
        "guidePage": null,
        "expanded": false,
        "defaultSearchCategory": false,
        "childCategories": [{
            "name": "cA-A-A",
            "leaf": false,
            "largeIconId": null,
            "label": "cA-A-A",
            "hideAllSearchFilters": false,
            "guidePage": null,
            "expanded": false,
            "defaultSearchCategory": false,
            "childCategories": [{
                "name": "cA-A-A-A",
                "leaf": false,
                "largeIconId": null,
                "label": "cA-A-A-A",
                "hideAllSearchFilters": false,
                "guidePage": null,
                "expanded": false,
                "defaultSearchCategory": false,
                "childCategories": [{
                    "name": "cA-A-A-A-A",
                    "leaf": true,
                    "largeIconId": null,
                    "label": "cA-A-A-A-A",
                    "hideAllSearchFilters": false,
                    "guidePage": null,
                    "expanded": false,
                    "defaultSearchCategory": false,
                    "childCategories": []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "cA-B",
        "leaf": true,
        "largeIconId": null,
        "label": "cA-B",
        "hideAllSearchFilters": false,
        "guidePage": null,
        "expanded": false,
        "defaultSearchCategory": false,
        "childCategories": []
    }, {
        "name": "cA-C",
        "leaf": true,
        "largeIconId": null,
        "label": "cA-C",
        "hideAllSearchFilters": false,
        "guidePage": null,
        "expanded": false,
        "defaultSearchCategory": false,
        "childCategories": []
    }]
}, {
    "name": "A",
    "leaf": false,
    "largeIconId": null,
    "label": "A",
    "hideAllSearchFilters": false,
    "guidePage": null,
    "expanded": false,
    "defaultSearchCategory": false,
    "childCategories": [{
        "name": "A-Level1",
        "leaf": false,
        "largeIconId": null,
        "label": "A-Level1",
        "hideAllSearchFilters": false,
        "guidePage": null,
        "expanded": false,
        "defaultSearchCategory": false,
        "childCategories": [{
            "name": "A-Level2",
            "leaf": true,
            "largeIconId": null,
            "label": "A-Level2",
            "hideAllSearchFilters": false,
            "guidePage": null,
            "expanded": false,
            "defaultSearchCategory": false,
            "childCategories": []
        }]
    }]
}];
```

Comment: So do that. If you run into a *specific* problem with it, post a new question with A) A clear explanation of what you want, including the desired result; and B) Your code attempting to produce that result from the input.

Comment: Separately: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it.  There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scan past it to find the button) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proposal in Vanilla.js with [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in a recursive fashion.

```js
function getNames(a) {
    this.push(a.name);
    Array.isArray(a.childCategories) && a.childCategories.forEach(getNames, this);
}

var data = [{ "name": "cA", "leaf": false, "largeIconId": null, "label": "cA", "hideAllSearchFilters": false, "guidePage": null, "expanded": false, "defaultSearchCategory": false, "childCategories": [{ "name": "cA-A", "leaf": false, "largeIconId": null, "label": "cA-A", "hideAllSearchFilters": false, "guidePage": null, "expanded": false, "defaultSearchCategory": false, "childCategories": [{ "name": "cA-A-A", "leaf": false, "largeIconId": null, "label": "cA-A-A", "hideAllSearchFilters": false, "guidePage": null, "expanded": false, "defaultSearchCategory": false, "childCategories": [{ "name": "cA-A-A-A", "leaf": false, "largeIconId": null, "label": "cA-A-A-A", "hideAllSearchFilters": false, "guidePage": null, "expanded": false, "defaultSearchCategory": false, "childCategories": [{ "name": "cA-A-A-A-A", "leaf": true, "largeIconId": null, "label": "cA-A-A-A-A", "hideAllSearchFilters": false, "guidePage": null, "expanded": false, "defaultSearchCategory": false, "childCategories": [] }] }] }] }, { "name": "cA-B", "leaf": true, "largeIconId": null, "label": "cA-B", "hideAllSearchFilters": false, "guidePage": null, "expanded": false, "defaultSearchCategory": false, "childCategories": [] }, { "name": "cA-C", "leaf": true, "largeIconId": null, "label": "cA-C", "hideAllSearchFilters": false, "guidePage": null, "expanded": false, "defaultSearchCategory": false, "childCategories": [] }] }, { "name": "A", "leaf": false, "largeIconId": null, "label": "A", "hideAllSearchFilters": false, "guidePage": null, "expanded": false, "defaultSearchCategory": false, "childCategories": [{ "name": "A-Level1", "leaf": false, "largeIconId": null, "label": "A-Level1", "hideAllSearchFilters": false, "guidePage": null, "expanded": false, "defaultSearchCategory": false, "childCategories": [{ "name": "A-Level2", "leaf": true, "largeIconId": null, "label": "A-Level2", "hideAllSearchFilters": false, "guidePage": null, "expanded": false, "defaultSearchCategory": false, "childCategories": [] }] }] }],
    names = [];

data.forEach(getNames, names);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(names, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```